# Using layered navigation without is_anchor category attribute

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, filter

Is it possible to use and display the layered navigation filtering when setting the anchor attribute to false?
I don't want to set anchor to true, because I don't want products of child categories to display.

Any tips?

Comment: You got the solution? If yes means post the answer

Comment: @Prabhu Unfortunately I don't. Decided to only use anchor on categories which don't have sub-categories.